# TipTap React Image Uploader with Placeholder

Tags: reactjs, tiptap

I am trying to build plug in the image extension (`@tiptap/extension-image`) to my tiptap editor, however the issue I find is with bigger images, there is no easy way to add a sort of placeholder image or text to tell the user the image is being uploaded.

The current flow is this:

```
const imageUrl = await doUpload();
editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: imageUrl }).run()
```

So between uploading the image and setting the image, there is a delay and no feedback to the user.

So I have tried to extend the Image extension and I am able to create a method to set some text, but then I am not sure how to clear that text. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: Have you solved this issues? Otherwise could you share your the code that you had an issue with and I could try to help you

Comment: Unfortunately not, i couldnt find a solution.